# Can I create a UIContainerView programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, uicontainerview

I'm trying to create a dynamic view flow that uses `UIContainerView`s to host `UIViewController`s. The `UIContainerView`s (or `UIViewController`s) need to be programmatically added to the `UIView` to allow multiple side by side.

I've been looking around, but can't find any constructors I can use to create my `UIContainerView`.

Is there a simple way to do this or is it against normal guidelines for creating reusable views?

To sum up, I want to achieve something like this:

```swift
var containerView = UIContainerView()
containerView.add(myViewController)
```

Comment: You could just add the views of the other ViewControllers to your "ContainerView" and control the views programmatically.

Comment: @JacobsonTalom I considered this, but I'm wondering if there would be any draw back. If for instance I performed any actions on the UIViewController once they've been "added", wouldn't that cause some inconsistency or problems if the UIViewControllers are not actually added to the View themselves?

Comment: Well, like Simon McLoughlin said in his answer: you should also add the ViewControllers as children etc (see his answer). If you want an example in swift I can post an example for you.

Comment: That won't be needed, I can convert the Obj-C code :). You can however post it as an answer to help others, that is always appreciated.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A `UIContainerView` is just a visual way to add a viewController as a child of another and setting its bounds.

You can do this programatically by adding the second viewController as a child of the first, taking the second's view and placing it somewhere on the first's view.

Something like this;

```
childVC = [[SomeViewController alloc] init];

[self addChildViewController:childVC];

[self.view addSubview:childVC.view];

[childVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Comment: If any actions are performed on the childViewController reference will it handle them correctly? For instance, a presentViewController method, despite it not physically being part of the UI as only the .view property has been added?

Comment: @Chackle all interactions will be handled by the logic inside `SomeViewController`. It functions as though both viewControllers are on the screen at the same time, independent of each other. If the user scrolls a scrollView on the parent, the parent will be notified, if the user scrolls a scrollView on the child, the childVC will be notified. The only difference is that the parent has to manage the lifecycle of the childVC