# Creating a UIContainerView() programmatically and changing its height

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uicontainerview

I'm creating a container view programmatically. However, i'm not able to change its height. I'm setting it programmatically but without any effect.

```
let supportView: UIView = UIView()
let containerView = UIView()

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)
    self.containerView.frame =  CGRect(x: self.view.frame.size.width - 100, y: 200, width: 225, height: 70)
    print(self.containerView.frame.height)
    self.containerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
    self.containerView.layer.cornerRadius = 20

    self.view.addSubview(self.containerView)

    let controller = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Storyboard2")
    addChildViewController(controller)

    containerView.addSubview(controller.view)
    controller.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
}
```

I created the view controller with identifier "Storyboard2" in the storyboard. And i've set its height to 70 there too. But without any luck.
Any Help? Thanks

Comment: Have u added constraints in story board ? Do you really have a need to create the container view programatically ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I create a UIContainerView programatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29694628/can-i-create-a-uicontainerview-programatically)

Comment: As a side note, there is no such thing as `UIContainerView()`.

Comment: Yes, but without any luck :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not set the `clipsToBounds` on `containerView`, and the default value of that property is `false`.

Add this line just under you are setting the `containerView`'s frame:

`containerView.clipsToBounds = true`

Also, as some reading material, i would like to present to you [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449256/how-does-clipstobounds-work) about the `clipsToBounds` property.